# Usual phrase for "Quarterly financial results"

Tags: phrase-requests, business-language

The question basically explains it... I'm looking for a phrase commonly used when you are referring for your business quarterly/monthly/bimonthly report of losses and gains and expenditures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *Profit and Loss Statement*, often abbreviated to "P&L".

> A profit and loss statement (P&L) is a financial statement that summarizes the revenues, costs and expenses incurred during a specific period of time, usually a fiscal quarter or year. These records provide information about a company's ability – or lack thereof – to generate profit by increasing revenue, reducing costs, or both. The P&L statement is also referred to as "statement of profit and loss", "income statement," "statement of operations," "statement of financial results," and "income and expense statement."
>   [- INVESTOPEDIA](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/plstatement.asp)

Profit and Loss statements are often accompanied by Balance Sheets as well:

> A balance sheet is a financial statement that summarizes a company's assets, liabilities and shareholders' equity at a specific point in time.
>   [- INVESTOPEDIA](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/balancesheet.asp)

The more generic term for these documents is *financial statements*:

> Financial statements for businesses usually include income statements, balance sheets, statements of retained earnings and cash flows.
>   [- INVESTOPEDIA](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/financial-statements.asp)

Comment: The "Balance Sheet" is also an important part of the monthly/quarterly accounts. Layouts for these things tend to be individually designed to suit individual businesses' needs. "Monthly Accounts Package" or "Monthly Financial Report" are just two of a multitude of names I've seen.

Comment: @WS2 Thanks, I've edited my answer to incorporate the term *balance sheet*.